# Проблема с обработкой данных из msql

Tags: php, mysql, mpdf

Есть несколько таблиц:

- `orders` - основные данные заказов,
- `order_item` - товары в заказе,
- `products` - информация о товарах,
- `clients` - клиенты компании,
- `admin` - таблица с администраторами системы.

Получается вывести данные из БД в файл, но не получается их кастомизировать под "нужды".

Код:

```
$wh = $conn->query('SELECT orders.*,clients.*,adm.*,oi.*, pos.*  FROM orders AS orders 
INNER JOIN clients ON orders.client=clients.cl_id 
INNER JOIN admin AS adm ON orders.admin_id=adm.admin_ID 
INNER JOIN order_item AS oi ON orders.id  =oi.order_id 
INNER JOIN products AS pos ON  oi.product_id= pos.p_id WHERE orders.date = "'.$_GET['date'].'"');
    

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/vendor/autoload.php';

// This will output the barcode as HTML output to display in the browser
     $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8','A4');
     

$ss = $wh->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($ss as $ord){
$table .= "<table><tr><td>".$ord['p_name']."</td></tr></table><br>";

}

$mpdf->WriteHTML('

'.$table.'


');
$mpdf->Output('docs/Отчет по заказам -'.$_GET['i'].'.pdf');
header('Location: docs/Отчет по заказам -'.$_GET['i'].'.pdf');
```

[image: Желаемый результат]

[image: Добился только вот этот ужас]

Comment: отсортируйте по заказу. Пробегитесь по массиву и  разделите данные на отдельные заказы, потом уже двойной цикл будет по обработке. В целом не обязательно все тащить одним запросом. Можно и разделить на отдельные, чтобы один вытаскивал перечень товаров заказов, а другой инфу, конткты и прочее. Ибо умножать строки у вас будут именно товары в заказе.

Comment: @teran , не могли бы вы пожалуйста написать это в виде кода, а то голова уже кипит… не могу нечего толком написать

Comment: @DrMcSheen, мне нужно, чтобы в пдф файле все отображалось как на первом фото, то есть по каждому заказу отдельный блок. Получается вывести все заказы и информацию по ним через $table .=“ но при попытки разбить эти данные на отдельные ячейки по каждому заказу разделяется каждая строка, даже та что в одном заказе, выводятся они как и в заказе, каждый товар, но отдельную таблицу по заказу не получается создать. Если есть какие идеи по коду, буду очень признателен, сижу с этой фигней уже 3-й день, найти и вспомнить ничего не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Пишу в ответ, ибо в комментах код несмотрибельный. Вот здесь у тебя для каждого значения каждый раз создаётся новая таблица с одним полем на строке.

```
$table .= "<table><tr><td>".$ord['p_name']."</td></tr></table><br>";
```

А если тебе надо в одну таблицу вставить несколько строк, делай так:

```
$table = "<table>";
foreach($ss as $ord){
    $table .= 
        "<tr>   // следующая строка
            <td>".$ord['p_name']."</td>    // столбцы в строке
            <td>".$ord['p_count']."</td>   // столбцы в строке
            <td>".$ord['p_price']."</td>   // столбцы в строке
            <td>".$ord['p_all']."</td>   // столбцы в строке
        </tr>";
}
$table .= "</table><br>";
```